# Genetically improved *Leucaena leucocephala* seeds

Tags: genetics, botany, growth

I am looking for fast growing *[Leucaena leucocephala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucaena_leucocephala)* seeds. Now, I am cultivating *[Leucaena leucocephala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucaena_leucocephala)* which can grow 6 meters in a year. But I am looking for a genetically improved seed which can grow up to 10 Meters in a year.

Comment: I am not saying it is off-topic. But can you repost this on: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/